# How to get broadcast ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED on Android 8

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to make an app that shows some information when you connect your phone to a charger during a specific period of the day.

Before Android Oreo this was easy, just add an Broadcast receiver and add android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED to the intentfilter in the manifest.

Now I am struggling to find a working solution to create the same functionality.
I thought about periodically checking the device charging state but this feels wrong and it won't trigger immediately on connecting the device to a charger.

Registering the broadcast receiver from my application did not work either, when the application is closed the broadcast isn't received anymore.

Is there a battery friendly way to trigger an action when an Android device is connected to a charger in Android Oreo?

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) which are exempted from the [background execution limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) and for which broadcast receivers can still be registered in the manifest.

You could use the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast to start a service which registers a receiver for your ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED broadcast at runtime. (The service must be a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). Otherwise, it may be destroyed.)

A other solution would be to use JobScheduler to create a job which [requires charging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#isRequireCharging). Then you don't need the foreground service.

Comment: I used the foreground service for all android versions beyond N.The service registers a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED. Next I used a  BOOT_COMPLETE BroadcastReceiver to start the foreground service.

For earlier Android versions I have used the standard method of using a BroadcastReceiver and adding ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED to the manifest.

Comment: @Matt ke, will the second suggested solution - to create a JobScheduler, work even if my app is killed? I mean will it trigger just as if I had used receiver in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, your job will be executed even if your app was killed.

Comment: If I use a jobscheduler , will it work “every time” the power is connected Or only once after the job is scheduled?

Comment: @1-0-1Development I cannot register a receiver for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED broadcast at runtime for android post 8, could you share the code?